# How to loop through controls to get specific type of controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, linq, controls

I have a div like this:

```
<div id="columns" runat="server">
       <ul id="column1" class="column" >
        <!-- /////////////// -->
        </ul>
        <ul id="column2" class="column" runat="server">
        </ul>
        <ul id="column3" class="column" runat="server">
        </ul>
        <ul id="column4" class="column" runat="server">
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

---

In run time I create **listitems(`HtmlGenericControl outer_li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");`)** in the (`ul` which has attribute `runat ="server"`).

Now what i wanna to do is:
looping through `div id="columns"` to get each (`ul` which has attribute `runat ="server"`) then loop through each (ul) to get each list item to save contents .

---

## EDIT: according to answers:

```
foreach (Control c in columns.Controls.OfType<HtmlGenericControl>())
        {
            var ctrl = (HtmlGenericControl)c;

            if (ctrl.TagName == "ul" && ctrl.ID != "column1")
            {
                foreach (Control li in ctrl.Controls.OfType<HtmlGenericControl>())
                {

                    var ctrl_li = (HtmlGenericControl)li;
                    if (ctrl_li.TagName == "li")
                    {
                        string id = ctrl_li.ID;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

this doesn't work i can't get the 'li' at all although there are `li` on my page

---

## Edit 2:

```
 protected void CreateBlockOfData(string widget_color, int column_par, string process_name, int block_type, int block_id)
        {
            HtmlGenericControl outer_li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
            outer_li.Attributes.Add("class", widget_color);
            if (column_par == 1)
            {
                column1.Controls.Add(outer_li);
            }
            else if (column_par == 2)
            {
                //uppnl_2.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(outer_li);
                column2.Controls.Add(outer_li);
            }
            else if (column_par == 3)
            {
                column3.Controls.Add(outer_li);
            }
            else if (column_par == 4)
            {
                column4.Controls.Add(outer_li);
            }
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            HtmlGenericControl div_head = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
            div_head.Attributes.Add("class", "widget-head");
            outer_li.Controls.Add(div_head);
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            HtmlGenericControl h3 = new HtmlGenericControl("h3");
            div_head.Controls.Add(h3);
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            Label lbl_process_name = new Label();
            lbl_process_name.Text = process_name.TrimEnd();
            h3.Controls.Add(lbl_process_name);
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            HtmlGenericControl div_content = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
            div_content.Attributes.Add("class", "widget-content");
            outer_li.Controls.Add(div_content);
            ////////////////////////Data//////////////////////////////
            Control crl_data = FormTheData(block_type, block_id);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(crl_data);
            crl_data.DataBind();
            div_content.Controls.Add(crl_data);
        }
```

Comment: -Why not use `BulletedList` class here?

Comment: If you are adding those `<li>`'s as html-text to the placeholder, then they are *not* 'Controls' as far as ASP.Net is concerned. You can't add a 'runat=server' as plain attribute to make it a Control, you would need to add it as HtmGenericControl or something like that.

Comment: Can you check my last edit please ?

Answer (score 1):

I tested this and added some `<li>`'s manually. I could get them to show up if I set `runat="server"` in their tag. So the code you're using to generate and add the ListItems is not creating them with the runat.

**Edit**
You made need to consider using an actual ASP .NET Control such as a DataGrid or Repeater or BulletedList as MAW74656 suggested instead of HTML `<ul>`'s.

Comment: hmmm, I try to add attribute .
`outer_li.Attributes.Add("runat","server");`
but invain..although it appears in the view source and with `runat="server"`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could change your list to use the ASP listitem control, which would allow you to...

Try something like this.  Using is to cast a control for testing is efficient.

```
  foreach (Control c in Page.Controls)
    {
        if (c is ListItem)
        {
            //do something with the control
        }
    }
```