# How to make an HtmlGenericControl attribute runat = "server".to access it from the code?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, controls, htmlgenericcontrol

I face a strange problem to access some `HtmlGenericControl` which created in run time .

How to make the `HtmlGenericControl` `runat ="server"`?so i can access it

---

```
 HtmlGenericControl myli = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
```

Comment: you can already access it in code.

myli.doSomething()

Comment: no , i can't .this is the real problem http://stackoverflow.com/q/9364016/418343

Comment: Can you hash the controls as you generate them and preserve a pointer to the control as you create it?

Comment: Could u explain more how to do this please ,sample or example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right because runat is interpeted at compile time it actually creates the control in the .designer file which is basically what you are doing in you .cs (code behind) So creating the control at runtime you need to manually create your Control tree, something that would happen automatically if you were using the designer.

I believe you would create some kind of Structure, Array, Dictionary etc. that would map a list of li's to their parrent UL then you can interate those in code by pulling a list of li's by the UL key that the li's are hashed to.

A Map of lists if you will. So Map.get("ulKey") returns a list of li's you can now iterate and run appropriate code on. Make sense?

Comment: Make sense but this not help me in my case, because the user through some jquery functions change properties of the listitems and i save these changes before the user leave the site .

Comment: So if you want to save the changes, just iterate all the maps and save the changes? no?

Comment: the maps will be old version, the user makes changes client side ,and i wanna to access the controls to store these properties

Comment: they should still be valid pointers to the actual control, it doesn't copy the control the variable it is just a pointer. so you should still be able to read from the control to save changes. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301569.aspx I believe this falls under "Reference Type" rather than "value type".

Comment: I will be grateful if U write a simple example .

Comment: You are correct i coded this up and I was totally wrong. This is however because element attributes are not tracked as part of the view state, and they are not submited as part of the form. I do not think this would work anyway you approached it other than a custom ajax plugin that decodes the li's and submits them as part of the form and then reconstructs them in the pageload.

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating any `HtmlGenericControl` at run time that means is server control and you can use it in your code easily and if you want to use any HTML control which exists on .aspx page at that time use this way to convert this HTML control to server control.

1. Add 2 new properties in this HTML Controls `runat="server"` and `id="id"` in the HTML control.

Comment: From firebug :

`<li id="l91" class="widget color-red" runat="server" style="">
<div class="widget-head" style="cursor: move;">
<div class="edit-box" style="display: none;">
<div class="widget-content">
</li>`

Comment: @just_name : and what about <UL> Please make it <ul runat="server" id="ul"> and then check this..